# Multiple pointers to a reallocated memory block in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Suppose I have multiple pointers to a block of heap memory.  Let's say the first pointer is the ***owner*** of the memory and there are several additional pointers that act as ***handles*** throughout my application.  So long as the owner is the only one which is `free`'d, we don't have a memory leak nor do we double free a block of memory.

```
/* Here is the owner */
size_t block_size = SOME_BLOCK_SIZE;
char *owner = malloc(block_size);

/* And a few handles that access the block in different places */
char *handle_1 = owner[10];
char *handle_2 = owner[359];
char *handle_3 = owner[172];
```

So far so good.  Later we `realloc` the owner to increase the capacity

```
char *tmp = realloc(owner, 2 * SOME_BLOCK_SIZE);
if (!tmp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not reallocate array\n");
    exit(-1);
}

if (tmp == owner) {
    printf("We all know what happens here...\n");
    printf("the owner array just increased size\n");
}
else {
    printf("We had to move the owner array to a new memory address\n");
    printf("What happens to the handles?\n");
}
```

There are three possible outcomes:

1. `realloc` fails because there is no more memory.
2. `realloc` successfully extends the array without having to move it.
3. `realloc` successfully extends the array, but it's moved to a new region of memory.

My question is, in case 3 what happens to the handles we defined earlier?  I would expect that since they are just pointer variables and since the `realloc` function is unaware of their existence, the handles are still pointing to the old memory address.  It's very easy to imagine things going bad.

Is my intuition correct?  If so, what's the best way around this (other than to never resize)?  I am afraid I am just going to have to keep a list of my active handles and update them when I detect the `owner` has been moved.  I have an idea on how to implement this, but I would rather use someone else's clever solution than to poorly re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Yes, the other pointers also need to be updated after a `realloc`. Lots of options here – store them as offsets instead of pointers, for example, so you only need to update one base pointer.

Comment: Storing the offset is a simple and clever idea.  Unfortunately, I need the pointer address since in my application these are consumed by a `gsl_matrix_view` (a structure that lets you view an array as a 2D matrix).  I think I need to write a hook to update my matrix views when I detect the underlying array has been resized.

Comment: Don't copy the owner' s content but pass around/distriubute it's address only.

Comment: As someone who writes a lot of multithreaded apps, this overall design is.. worrying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like ryan and true recommend, you should use an base pointer(owner). This base pointer can be update in the case of an realloc. Your handles should be managed as offsets to this base pointer.

```
int handle1_off = 10;
int handle2_off = 359;
...
```

If you want to access the handle you must calculate the actual pointer.

```
memcpy(owner + handle1_off, some_other_pointer, some_size);
```